# Will I keep my game progress if I buy a game currently shared through Family Sharing?

Tags: steam, the-witcher-3, steam-family-sharing

I've been playing The Witcher 3 through a shared Steam library. Now I want to buy it for myself, because whenever the person who's library I'm using plays a game, I cannot access their games or will get kicked if I'm playing when they try to play something.

If I buy my own copy from Steam, will my progress/saves still be there?

Comment: I imagine that for the majority of games - yes - you will keep your progress as it's still the same Steam App ID, and likely saved on your local disk somewhere, but I can't be certain as I haven't used Family Sharing before.

Comment: Starbound kept all my items and customized stuff when I purchased it after playing hours on my buddies copy. I was able to quickly purchase the game, hop right back in, and was playing with him in a couple minutes. I assume that this is blanket steam policy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. This question has been asked a few times on here, but the short answer is yes.

You'll keep all of your stats, achievements, inventory items etc if you buy the game for yourself, since they're independent to your Steam ID, as well as being stored onto your PC (or Steam Cloud), rather than the person who owned the game originally.